# Twilio IP Commands error "device was not attached to a cellular network"

Tags: iot, twilio-api

I used different APNs as per Twilio docs: super, sg1.super, and de1.super.  I'm actually closer to sg1 and when I put that it started working.  I got IP Commands as "sent" status.  but it only worked briefly.  Then, all commands go to "error: device was not attached to a cellular network".

Even when I get this error I see download/upload in usage.

I know the provider it's using is reliable, but can it be that the cellphone provider is rejecting my Twilio SIM card?  Well I don't think that is how roaming works anyway.

This is the code.  Rarely it works and command is "sent", mostly it does not work and error is "not attached to network".

```
      .create({ sim: sim, payload: payload, devicePort: devicePort, callbackUrl: callbackUrl })
      .then(ip_command => {
        console.log(ip_command.sid);
        res.status(200).send("done");
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send("error");
      });
```

This is the error

```
DEFAULT 2023-05-30T22:57:51.435546Z [resource.labels.functionName: lockFunction] [labels.executionId: y45coz2jhd8t] ErrorMessage: 'The device was not attached to a cellular network',
```

I'm tried changing the port, and it did not work.

Anyone here a Twilio Super Sim/IP command expert?